# Revoke access token when user navigates away from SPA

Tags: reactjs, openid-connect, react-oidc

I am developing SPA applications using ReactJS and the `react-oidc-context` library. All of these SPAs are OIDC-protected Wizards that the user closes/leaves once the wizard is complete.

When the user closed/leaves the wizard, I want to revoke the access tokens they were issued when they initially launched the wizard.

Putting a 'Close' button that revokes the token when the user completes the wizard is easy enough. However, I am stuck on detecting when the user attempts to close/cancel the wizard prematurely. For example, the user starts the wizard and then navigates away to another site. When that occurs, I want to revoke the access token.

How can I detect when a user tries to close/navigate away from a wizard?

Answer (score 0):

use the cleanup function in react useEffect

```ts
useEffect(() => {
  
  return () => {
    // executed when a component gets unmounted, i.e. the user left the wizard
    dispatch(removeToken()); // if you are using redux

  };
}, []);
```

Comment: Would this go in the `index.js`, `app.js` or in your `Home` component?